# Whats the difference between AND and WHERE in the join statement

Tags: sql

I've been sitting at W3 schools and scratching my brain, by not understanding why the result changes when i execute some SQL commands.

So this is W3 schools example:

```
SELECT Employees.LastName, COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Employees ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
where LastName = 'Davolio' OR LastName = 'Fuller'
GROUP BY LastName
HAVING COUNT(Orders.OrderID) > 25;
```

The output result is: Davolio   29

So my question is, when i change the code to

```
SELECT Employees.LastName, COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Employees ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
and LastName = 'Davolio' OR LastName = 'Fuller'
GROUP BY LastName
HAVING COUNT(Orders.OrderID) > 25;
```

The output result is: Davolio   29  Fuller  196

What is happening here, I have not found a proper explanation for why Fuller of 196 orders comes up when just changing it to AND, why is there a difference?

Comment: The join condition in the second query is missing a parenthesis. The current one is: `Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID and LastName = 'Davolio' OR LastName = 'Fuller'`; so in this query, if the last  name is `Fuller`, then the whole condition becomes true. It should be: `Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
and (LastName = 'Davolio' OR LastName = 'Fuller')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic in the second case is:

```
ON (Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID and LastName = 'Davolio') OR
   (LastName = 'Fuller')
```

You would get the same results with parentheses:

```
ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID and
   (LastName = 'Davolio' OR LastName = 'Fuller')
```

Or more simply with `IN`:

```
ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID and
   LastName IN ('Davolio', 'Fuller')
```

Comment: Interesting.... Didn't know about the parenthesis. So why does 196 comes up then, since the real result is 20.